autodesplazarse para mostrar el elemento expandido cuando lo selecciono en el recyclerview
Me gustaría saber como hacer posible que cuando seleccione un item del recyclerview, al expandirse se desplace un poco para mostrar el elemento expandido al completo y no tener que desplazar manualmente la lista.
Pero me gustaría que fuese en general, no solo para el ultimo elemento de la lista, sino para cualquiera que esté por la parte inferior de la pantalla
Muchas Gracias
Fragment Principal
private int lastposition;
ArrayList<Model> lista;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todos, container, false);

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_arrowverso);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Capitulos();

        adapter = new ListAdapter(lista, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (currentSearchText.isEmpty()){
                    lastposition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

El Adaptador del Recyclerview
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Model bloger = modelArrayList.get(position);

        boolean isExpandable = modelArrayList.get(position).isExpandable();
        holder.relative_child.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        holder.relative_head.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                model.setExpandable(!model.isExpandable());
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

